# Editing of closed posts

Tags: discussion

I  recently reviewed an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/609763) to a closed post. At first glance this seemed superfluous as it seemed pointless to edit a post that had already been closed as off-topic so I rejected the post and upon hitting the button noticed that the editor had added a plea towards relevance to 16.04 though the post in question was written about 13.04 and tagged as such. If I had read it more thouroughly I may have simply improved the edit by removing the references to 13.04 (and that tag) If I had the power to reverse that choice I might do so. Would that be the appropriate thing to do in this case?

Comment: To me, that edit seems pointless, the question was written in 2013 and then closed. Also the edit did was rearrange words. Even if this is relevant to 16.04 (no evidence for this is given, just a claim) why bring back this old dead question? It has had its views and is already closed. It is dead and beyond revival now. IMO, a new question is better that digging up long dead ones.